# How do i use php to divide sql results into two columns if there are more than 8 results?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a footer on my website that has two links, by each other, that each can hold 8 links. How do i use php to divide the links into two sections but only if there are more than 8 results.This is what i have to display it right now.

```
<?php
$footer_sql = "SELECT title, link,widget FROM footer WHERE widget='1'";
$result = $db->query($footer_sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0 AND $result->num_rows < 8) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<li><a href='".$row["link"]."'>". $row["title"] . "</a></li>";
    }
elseif ($result->num_rows > 0 AND $result->num_rows > 8) {
    //// This is where the thing would go to show 2 columns
}
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if you have 8 links?

Comment: Generate the output you want in the elseif. You are almost all the way there

Comment: I dont know how to use the operators like that

Comment: What operators? You have already coded it. Now just output the HTML you want to make 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// create array of your result 
$footer_sql = "SELECT title, link,widget FROM footer WHERE widget='1'";
$result = $db->query($footer_sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    $result = $result->fetch_assoc();

else 
    echo "Error";


//create array for both section 

for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++ )
{
    if(i<8)
    {
         $section1[] = $result[$i];

    }
    else
    {

         $section2[] = $result[$i];
    }
}

//now print to your html using foreach

foreach($section1 as $sec1)
{
     //print in second col
    echo "<li><a href='".$sec1["link"]."'>". $sec1["title"] . "</a></li>";
}

foreach($section2 as $sec2)
{
     //print in second col
    echo "<li><a href='".$sec2["link"]."'>". $sec2["title"] . "</a></li>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me